# iOS generating random message

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hello this is the iOS project I'm working on .
I'm just a beginner at programming iOS apps.
I just need help so that I can improve ><

Here's my app so far.[image: iPhone Test]

So my job is under the reminder that shows the box " Daily Vibes".
I need to include 100 messages randomly.

I've heard of arc random function. I just need some examples on how to do use it.

Here's my code :

AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Daily Vibes"
                                                        message:notification.alertBody
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
```

AddtoDoViewController.m

```
    implementation AddToDoViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.itemText.delegate = self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    [self.itemText resignFirstResponder];

    // Get the current date
    NSDate *pickerDate = [self.datePicker date];

    // Schedule the notification
    UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate = pickerDate;
    localNotification.alertBody = self.itemText.text;
    localNotification.alertAction = @"Show me the item";
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

    // Request to reload table view data
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadData" object:self];

    // Dismiss the view controller
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self.itemText resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
@end
```

I would like some assistance please.

Thank you.

Expectation :

With the box

Daily Vibes

-Attached 100 random messages-

Example of the affirmation :

```
NSarray *100affirmations = @[@"Every day in every way I am getting happier and happier.",
                            @"I am thankful to everybody who has touched my life and made it worth living. ",
                            @"Happiness is contagious. My happiness makes all these people happy, thus making it one big happy world.",
                            @"My happy disposition attracts happiness into my life and I only interact with happy people and have only happy experiences.",
                            @"I spread happiness to others and absorb happiness from others. I enjoy every moment of the day.",
                            @"Be happy is my motto and happiness is not a destination. It’s my way of life.",
                            @"I am living my life, feeling motivated and excited about the greatness I am creating, on a daily basis.",
                            @"I am going to make the best out of my life. I will appreciate all opportunities which are given to me and follow my way.",
```

Comment: Are you talking about generating random sentences that make sense to a human reader, because if you are that's a university PhD study topic in itself and no way anybody can answer that. If you already have 100 sentences and you want to pick them randomly then thats a different matter. Which is it?

Comment: @MartinH, I have 100 sentences in my notepad . I have idea of doing but my thread keep on breaking at the AppDelegate.M , NSarray for 100 affirmation and by using x=arc4random_uniform. I've tried a lot of method even ipsum but no luck :(

Still i'm trying my best how to make it possible. If a rookie or senior overcome a PhD study topic , then they don't need a piece of PhD to recognize their skills.

Comment: @MartinH , i've just included example of the 100 sentences . Have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your messages in an NSMutableArray and the following method will be good enough for your purposes I think:

```
+ (void) randomOrderedMutableArray:(NSMutableArray *) array
{
    int count = [array count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        int nElements = count - i;
        int n = (arc4random() % nElements) + i;
        [array exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm new to NSmutable array .

Can I do something like this :

NSMutableArray *affirmiation = @[@"hello",@"gg",@"kill them"]; ?

Comment: Exactly like that, actually.

Comment: Let me try to wit this method .

because i also google there's method like this :

NSString *a = @"a";
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:a,nil];

So i'll need to attach this to the AppDelegate.m? or viewtodocontroller.m? which is convenient cause when I was tuning around Viewtodocontroller , i kept on getting thread break.

Comment: Like the others, I may be a bit unclear, but what it looks like you're after is to create a list of phrases that will be picked at random.  You could initialize that in viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear in your view controller.  Not in the AppDelegate.

Comment: I get error for "No visible @interface for NSarray but my interface is affirmation.h is interface Affirmation: NSObject
{
 NSArray *affirmation;
}

Comment: Sorry, would need to see the source code.  NSarray?  That would be a typo -- should be NSArray always.

Comment: lol sorry for the typo .. i fixed it by doing this :

-(void)NSArray_Affirmation
{
    for(int i =0;i<[affirmation count];i++)
 {
  NSLog(@"%@",[affirmation objectAtIndex:i]);
 }